# how to concatenate string and number in prolog?

Tags: prolog, concatenation

let's say `Expr = 1+2.` and I want this `Expr` in parenthesis, what should I do in order to have this unification?

```
NewExpr = (1+2).
```

How can I make this `NewExpr` out from old `Expr`?

(ps: if you are interested - I'm doing a prefix to infix conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you manipulate terms, the problem is that `1 + 2` is equivalent to `(1 + 2)`. So you won't find a good solution I guess.

Though, that should not bother you since if you put that `Expr` into a more complicated term, the parenthesis will indeed be added accordingly.

```
?- Expr = 1 + 2, ComplicatedExpr =.. [+, 1, Expr].
Expr = 1+2,
ComplicatedExpr = 1+ (1+2).
```

If you don't know the `=../2` operator, you can read more about it [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2).